# Question about ethics migrated from programmers.se

Tags: support

Why was [this question about ethics and possibly law](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11025/what-should-i-do-when-my-boss-asks-me-to-fabricate-audit-log-data) migrated here from [programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)?

Does it belong? I've never been here before, so I dunno. Even though apparently I now have some rep here, thanks to my answer on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to IT and Information Security, this site covers topics such as IT Audit, some legal and ethical questions (although we don't profess to give legal guidance) and as the question was closed on Programmers through being voted off-topic I thought we would save it.

And welcome to security SE

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for saving the question... and for your kind welcome!

Comment: As noted in the comments to the actual question, I think you made a good decision! Legal issues are not something you want to get involved with here, I agree. But ethical concerns certainly are! You might want to consider protecting the question soon, or some other measure, as there are a lot of similar content responses piling up. We have that happen on English SE sometimes, with very high interest questions. Just a suggestion, not trying to tell you what to do, okay?

Comment: Good call @FeralOink - spotted that as I woke up today. Protected - thanks :-)